# using 2 lists rendered in javascript

Tags: java, javascript

I'm creating a tagCloud in my web application. I've a method that renders 2 lists:

```
public static void tagCloud(){
        List<Topic> topics = Topic.find("order by topicName asc").fetch();
        List<Tutorial> tutorials = Tutorial.find("order by id asc").fetch();
        List<Integer> topicCount = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i = 0; i < topics.size(); i++){
            int z = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j < tutorials.size(); j++){
                if (tutorials.get(j).getTopic().equals(topics.get(i))){
                    z++;
                    topicCount.add(z);

                }
            }
        }
        render (topics, topicCount);
    }
```

I want to use those 2 lists for the tagCloud in a line similar to this one:

```
<a href="/Topics/topicView?topicId=${topicList.id}" rel="8">${topicList.topicName.raw()}</a>
```

I want to use the indexes in topicCount list to be "rel" (size of the words) and topics to be the element itself to be shown, how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having two lists, I would store each topic with its count in a single object (let's call it `TopicWithCount`), and use a single `List<TopicWithCount>`.